# parsing XML in iOS : Tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, parsing

I have a XML file. 
This is a part of it.

```
<Placemark>
    <kml:name xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">Placename</kml:name>
    <kml:description xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    </kml:description>
    <kml:Point xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
      <kml:coordinates>121.142122637505,22.9071362429957,0</kml:coordinates>
    </kml:Point>
    <styleUrl>#ylwPng</styleUrl>
</Placemark>
```

And this is my code

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
  attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
NSString *ident = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"];

KMLStyle *style = [_placemark style] ? [_placemark style] : _style;

// Style and sub-elements
if (ELTYPE(Style)) {
    if (_placemark) {
        [_placemark beginStyleWithIdentifier:ident];
    } else if (ident != nil) {
        _style = [[KMLStyle alloc] initWithIdentifier:ident];
    }
} else if (ELTYPE(PolyStyle)) {
    [style beginPolyStyle];
} else if (ELTYPE(LineStyle)) {
    [style beginLineStyle];
} else if (ELTYPE(color)) {
    [style beginColor];
} else if (ELTYPE(width)) {
    [style beginWidth];
} else if (ELTYPE(fill)) {
    [style beginFill];
} else if (ELTYPE(outline)) {
    [style beginOutline];
}
// Placemark and sub-elements
else if (ELTYPE(Placemark)) {
    _placemark = [[KMLPlacemark alloc] initWithIdentifier:ident];
} else if (ELTYPE(Name)) {
    [_placemark beginName];
} else if (ELTYPE(Description)) {
    [_placemark beginDescription];
} else if (ELTYPE(styleUrl)) {
    [_placemark beginStyleUrl];
} else if (ELTYPE(Polygon) || ELTYPE(Point) || ELTYPE(LineString)) {
    [_placemark beginGeometryOfType:elementName withIdentifier:ident];
}
// Geometry sub-elements
else if (ELTYPE(coordinates)) {
    [_placemark.geometry beginCoordinates];
}
// Polygon sub-elements
else if (ELTYPE(outerBoundaryIs)) {
    [_placemark.polygon beginOuterBoundary];
} else if (ELTYPE(innerBoundaryIs)) {
    [_placemark.polygon beginInnerBoundary];
} else if (ELTYPE(LinearRing)) {
    [_placemark.polygon beginLinearRing];
}
}
```

But my code doesn't work. My code can only parse the following XML successfully.

```
     <Placemark>
        <name>Placename/name>
        <description></description>
        <styleUrl>#ylwPng</styleUrl>
        <Point> 
         <coordinates>121.142122637505,22.90713624299571,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
```

I am trying to alter it to suit my XML, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add one instance variable to remember the element name or the string object. 
For example, you can add   `NSString *_currentElement;` to store the element name, then you use it in the `NSXMLParserDelegate` as below:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    _currentElement = elementName;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"kml:name"]) {
        NSLog(@"url:%@",attributeDict[@"xmlns:kml"]);
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"kml:description"])
    {
        NSLog(@"url:%@",attributeDict[@"xmlns:kml"]);
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"kml:Point"])
    {
        NSLog(@"url:%@",attributeDict[@"xmlns:kml"]);
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([_currentElement isEqualToString:@"kml:coordinates"]) {
        NSLog(@"Coordinates:%@",string);
    }
    else if ([_currentElement isEqualToString:@"styleUrl"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Style:%@",string);
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

}
```

The above snippet should work for you.